# "No reactor running" when using Tokio + FFI and dynamic dispatch from a trait

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I know, quite the use case.

I am trying to build a plugin API for my application where the contract between plugins and the main executer are defined with a trait. I will use the `stable_abi` crate to achieve this but for now I am using `libloading` with Rust's built in FFI capabilities.

At its most basic I have a `dylib` crate (the plugin) and a `bin` crate (the executor). The executor consumes the `dylib` and calls methods on it.

[The most basic example is this:](https://github.com/alshdavid-scratch/tokio_ffi_dynamic_dispatch/blob/21401dd6b05017d114e1cc5b54c6f3cda3a560bf/a/src/main.rs)

```
/plugin
/executor

/target
  /debug
    executor
    plugin.so
```

```rust
// plugin/src/lib.rs
#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn add(left: usize, right: usize) -> usize {
    left + right
}
```

```rust
// executor/src/main.rs
fn main() {
  let exe_path = std::env::current_exe().unwrap();
  let exe_dir = exe_path.parent().unwrap();
  let lib_path = exe_dir.join("libplugin.so");

  unsafe {
    let lib = libloading::Library::new(&lib_path).unwrap();
    let add: libloading::Symbol<unsafe fn(usize, usize) -> usize> = lib.get(b"add").unwrap();
    println!("{}", add(1, 1));
  }
}
```

I then progressively add layers to it, moving towards a trait with methods that return futures:

- Working: "add()" returns a future
- [Working: "add()" returns a future within a tokio::task](https://github.com/alshdavid-scratch/tokio_ffi_dynamic_dispatch/blob/b34fe5165897a9b8da59fce1218f70f5fa21b2aa/b/src/lib.rs)
- [Working: Struct "Adder.add()" returns a future within a tokio::task](https://github.com/alshdavid-scratch/tokio_ffi_dynamic_dispatch/blob/f34cad7a7bdd1d1aaa6e4cfdb3b36f8ef00ab94f/c/src/lib.rs#L10)
- [Failing: Trait "Adder.add()" with an implementation that returns a future from a tokio::task](https://github.com/alshdavid-scratch/tokio_ffi_dynamic_dispatch/blob/456979b268f4d4a0c660adb1a4d4ad3cd79e366b/c/src/lib.rs#L10)

Tokio fails with:

```
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at c/src/lib.rs:12:13:
there is no reactor running, must be called from the context of a Tokio 1.x runtime
```

This failure occurs in `tokio::task::spawn` within the `AddMachine` struct, but only when the `.add()` method is called when it's in the form of a `Box<dyn Adder>`.

Why is this and is there a way around it?

Comment: You should probably add that failing example as a [mre] to the question. Otherwise many will simply not regard it (as it's not part of the question). The example you posted does not make any calls to any tokio function and as such can't produce that error.